# Finding an Xpath link on IMDB.com for the first drop down item in the search bar

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I can't seem to find the right Xpath for what I am trying to do:

[image]

the element I am trying to click on appears to be:

```
//*[@id="react-autowhatever-1--item-0"]/span/div[2]
```

but when run this code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(imdbScrape.driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                            '//*[@id="suggestion-search"]'))).send_keys("the"
                            + "fifth element")

searchBar = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                 '//*[@id="react-autowhatever-1--item-0"]/span/div[2]')))
searchBar.location_once_scrolled_into_view
urlToScrape = searchBar.get_attribute("href")

print(urlToScrape)
```

I get "None" as the result, I am assuming it because when I look on the page I don't see any "href" tags but I am wondering how I can get the first selection's link address

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please try (//li[@id='react-autowhatever-1--item-0']//div)[2]

Comment: `Div`s won't have a href. Mostly just `a`s have those.

Comment: Since there is no href anywhere in the searched result(assuming its handled by reactjs routes), you are better off clicking the li element and getting the link by using driver.current_url

Comment: That worked , thanks a lot !

Comment: Please upvote if you think the comment  helped :)

Comment: @AmithYR You don't gain any reputation if your comment is upvoted.

Comment: @DebanjanB Oh got it.